# Wifi drivers not installing

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, intel

I just got myself a laptop with a Intel dual band 8260 Wifi adapter and I've installed linux on it but it doesn't install my drivers. This is a modinfo for iwlwifi

`filename:       /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode`

I need iwlwifi-8260-12.ucode but I can't find it anywhere. I've tried using this link https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi but it still doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wifi driver and firmware are two different things driver is kernel dependent which you may have to compile your kernel or get the same from distro. but you can use firmware on https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ for almost all the supported wireless cards should clone it in /lib/firmware in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this ucode https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode

More info you can find on Intel wiki
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release